# How to move rectangles that intersect?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, rectangles

What I am trying to do , is create a method that checks every time if two rectangles of an array of rectangles intersect and if they do relocate one of the two rectangles somewhere else on the frame, but not over another rectangle.

```
Random rand = new Random();

Rec[0] = new Rectangle(100,100,50,50);


for(int i = 0; i<recs.length; i++){
    for(int j = i+1; j<recs.length;j++){
        if(recs[i].intersects(recs[j])){
            recs[i] = new Rectangle(rand.nextInt(501),rand.nextInt(501),50,50);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

frame size is 500x500
When I execute this code it still has rectangles that intersect.
What am I doing wrong?

package q1;

```
  import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;
    import java.util.Random;

    import javax.swing.JComponent;

    public class RectangleComponent extends JComponent{
        public Rectangle[] recs;
        private Random rand;
        RectangleComponent(){
            rand = new Random();
            recs = new Rectangle[6];
//these two intersect
            recs[0] = new Rectangle(100,100,50,50); 
            recs[1] = new Rectangle(110,90,50,50);
//
            recs[2] = new Rectangle(200,200,50,50);
            recs[3] = new Rectangle(300,300,50,50);
            recs[4] = new Rectangle(400,400,50,50);
            recs[5] = new Rectangle(250,250,50,50);
            for(int i = 0; i<recs.length; i++){
                for(int j = i+1; j<recs.length;j++){
                    if(recs[i].intersects(recs[j])){
                        recs[i] = new Rectangle(rand.nextInt(501),rand.nextInt(501),50,50);
                        repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            for(Rectangle x : recs){
                g2.draw(x);
            }
        }

    }

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RectangleViewer {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        RectangleComponent comp = new RectangleComponent();
        frame.add(comp);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

if you run it a few times eventually some rectangle will be over the other.

Comment: Are you really thinking that a random shift of an overlapping rectangle will always relocate it to a place where there is no rectangle?

Comment: you're doing the whole thing in a for-loop, which will only recreate rectangles once. now let's assume, your at the last rectangle in the outter loop. and your at the last round of the inner forloop. you're rectangle intersects with another rectangle, you recreate it and the loop breaks off. but you didn't check whether the new rectangle intersects with any rectangle

Comment: So , how should I do it?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Ok , I'll try to do that

Comment: You mean something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022688/array-creation-stack-overflow/29022867#29022867)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an optimal solution for your case but it will help you to fix your code based on random paint.

1. Suppose that you have **N** rectangles that do NOT intersect.
2. To add a new **N+1** rectangle you have to check that it doesn't intersect with previous **N** rectangles and then add it.

So in your case your algorithm based on random paint will look like this:

1. You are generating a random location of rectangle **K**
2. For all rectangles from **1** to **K-1** you check that they do not intersect with possible rectangle **K**
3. If there is an intersection you are getting back to #1.
4. If there are no intersections you are adding this rectangle and going to repeat all the steps for rectangle **K+1**

But please note that you can end up running an infinite loop if there is no enough space on your canvas.

You can think about an algorithm identifying a good location for a new rectangle or finding out that there is no space for it. Later you can replace you random method with your new method (Strategy pattern).